# Number of parts or pairs of parts verifying conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

Here is an Exercise from the following book [https://www.amazon.fr/Mathématiques-Méthodes-Exercices-MPSI-programme/dp/210072780X/ref=pd_sim_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=6KD4X5JTZGWMTDBXP238](https://www.amazon.fr/Math%C3%A9matiques-M%C3%A9thodes-Exercices-MPSI-programme/dp/210072780X/ref=pd_sim_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=6KD4X5JTZGWMTDBXP238) that i can't understand his solution specialy how the authour found These bijective maps to be able to calculate the number f parts X in differents cases.

http://www.dunod.com/sciences-techniques/sciences-fondamentales/mathematiques/classes-preparatoires/mathematiques-methodes-et-exercices-mpsi

**Exercise :**

> Number of parts or pairs of parts verifying conditions.
>
> Let $E$ be a finite set, $n = |E|, A ⊂ E, B ⊂ E, p = |A|, q = |B|, r = |A\cap B|$.
>
> - Determine the number of parts X of E such that:

- 1 $X \cup A = E$
- 2 .$A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B$

**Solutions provided by the book:**

The map $$Z\longmapsto \bar{A} \cup Z $$ is a bijection of the set of
All the parts $Z$ of $A$ on the set of the parts $X$ of $E$
Such that $X \cup A = E$.
The number sought is therefore the number of parts of $A$, that is
 $2^{p}$.

The map $$Z\longmapsto (A\cap B ) \cup Z $$ is a bijection of the set of parts of $(A\cup B )\setminus (A\cap B)$ onto the set of parts X of E such that $A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B$, so the number sought is the number of parts of $(A\cup B )\setminus (A\cap B)$ .
Since A ∩ B ⊂ A ∪ B, we have:

$$2^{card\left(A\cap B \subset X \subset A\cup B\right)}=2^{p+q-2r}$$

**My questions:**

- Could someone explain to me how the author of the book found these bijective maps to calculate the number of parts in differents cases.
- if isn't obvious should i memorize them

[image]

[image]

**My thoughts** about how the author found those bijection maps above

for case : $X \cup A = E$

$\forall X\subset E$;
\begin{aligned}
X\cup A=E &\iff \overline{X\cup A}=\emptyset \\
&\iff \overline{X} \subset A
\end{aligned} thus we have the the following bijective function:

\begin{align*}
f: \{ X\in\mathcal{P}\left(A\right), X\cup A=E  \} &\rightarrow \{Y\in \mathcal{P}\left(E \right), Y\subset A \}\\
  X&\mapsto \overline{X}
\end{align*}
i found bijection map but not the same as worte the author of the book

$P(X)$ means Power set of a set $X$

Comment: What is $E$? What is $A$? What is $B$? What does "number of parts" mean? What does this have to do with either probability or number theory?

Comment: please check my new edit it's clear now